# SQL Exception: The Timeout period elapsed ( after it previously fetched the result)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

As part of a new feature, some code that calls the following method was added

```
try
{
    using (var context = new TRContext())
    {
        var query = from option in context.Option
                    where option.package == package && option.type== type
                    select option;

        return query.DefaultIfEmpty(null).First();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error($"Failed to get Option by package='{package}' and type='{type}'", ex);
    return null;
}
```

This is called before as part of other functionality(and works fine), then when fetching it again, I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I've tried

- [How to use SqlAzureExecutionStrategy and "Nolock"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899382/how-to-use-sqlazureexecutionstrategy-and-nolock)
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/prevent-dead-lock-in-entity-framework/

or having `context.Databae.Connection.Open()`  but get other errors.

What could have led to this ? How could I fix it?

Comment: Can you add exception's stacktrace?

Comment: StackTrace  - https://justpaste.it/825ak